# Search list of strings in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I would need to search a few terms within two columns (Col1 and Col2) in a dataframe:

```
list_keys=['gatto','cane','dog','cat']

Col1           Col2         Col3       

gatto         zebra         zoo
micio         elefante      school
pollo         cane          park
cane          colibrì       garage
```

Expected output:

```
Col1           Col2         Col3       

gatto         zebra         zoo
pollo         cane          park
cane          colibrì       garage
```

To search a word in a column I have used `str.contains`. How can I also include an if statement for searching in a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `isin` + `any`

```
df = df[df[['Col1','Col2']].isin(list_keys).any(1)]
```

If not single word match

```
df[['Col1','Col2']].apply(lambda x : x.str.contains('|'.join(list_keys)))
```

Comment: I do not know why but it is giving me an empty dataframe.Could it be due to the fact that I have in the column not only a single word but also strings (e.g. `un gatto sotto il tavolo`)?

Comment: @LucaDiMauro I have update the answer with str contains

Comment: Thank you. It gives me True/False. Is there any way to see the rows as not boolean?

Comment: @LucaDiMauro you just need to df[df[['Col1','Col2']].apply(lambda x : x.str.contains('|'.join(list_keys)))]

Comment: Thank you @Yoben_S. Why are the other values (False) equal to nan? I thought it was just filtering the rows that contained the list of words

Comment: @LucaDiMauro df[df[['Col1','Col2']].apply(lambda x : x.str.contains('|'.join(list_keys))).any(1)]